# Javascript changing Body background-image and footer background image

Tags: javascript, css

Well the below code is working but a little problem which im unable to figure out is that `backImage` is the image to change the background image and the `ftImage` is the image to change the image of the footer it is changing the background image but not the footer background with class `#footer` from css file.

any help would be appreciated...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var backImage = new Array();
var ftImage = new Array();
var myElement = document.querySelector("#footer");

backImage[0] = "images/patterns/yellow.png";
ftImage[0] = "images/patterns/blue.png";
backImage[1] = "images/patterns/blue.png";
backImage[2] = "images/patterns/green.png";
backImage[3] = "images/patterns/brown.png";
backImage[4] = "images/patterns/grey.png";
backImage[5] = "images/patterns/red.png";
```

> ```
> function changeBGImage(whichImage){
>   if (document.body){
>     var footer = document.querySelector("#footer");
>    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+backImage[whichImage]+")";
>    //myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ftImage[whichImage]+")";
>    footer.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ftImage[whichImage]+")";
>    cookie.set('bgImage', whichImage, 365);
> }}
> ```

```
</script>
```

Comment: What are you passing into `changeBGImage`? You have an array for `backImage` which has 6 items in it and one for `ftImage` which only has 1 item in it; however, you're passing the same index to both of them. Posting the relevant HTML and CSS may help us figure out the issue.

Comment: `#footer` is an ID, not a class. Is it possible that's the reason why it's not working for your footer?

Comment: Also, where is this script placed? If it is in the head, the `#footer` element has not loaded yet and thus cannot be retrieved by `querySelector`. You'd have to run the script after the page is done loading (or at least after the `#footer` element has loaded).

Comment: even i put as id for footer. would you please tell me how to put class????

Comment: @SombreErmine i tried as u said but nothing. even that is in header after #footer

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML and CSS. It could be an issue with any of them. Also, what browser and version are you testing with? (`querySelector` may not be available in your browser)

Comment: I'm testing with firefox 28.0

Comment: `querySelector` should work then if it's used correctly. Unfortunately, no one can easily help you unless you post your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: all set now thanks... for your kind coordination... i put the cookie code in footer file also because it was added only in header. thanks alot @SombreErmine